# PHP update form that have dynamic drop down menu and also optgroup

Tags: php, dynamic, drop-down-menu, insert-update, optgroup

I try to create an update form for my system.
Basically, for update/edit, the form should show a current selected item (by id) from my **$row_rekod[dept'];**. But in my case, it just show the title which is **Jabatan**, and also the rest of items in **helpline_jabatan** table. You can see **$selected_jabatan** variable that I used to display my current selected item. But its not working.

Category (show in optgroup in drop down menu) = **$dept['kategori_jabatan'].**  All items shown in the list = **$dept['jabatan'].**

```
<select name="Jabatan" id="Jabatan">
option value="-1" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Jabatan</option>
<?php
$query_1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM helpline_jabatan ORDER BY no_jabatan ASC");
$depts = array();

while($row_1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_1)) {
    array_push($depts, $row_1);
    $selected_jabatan = $row_1['jabatan'] == $row_rekod['dept'] ? ' selected="selected"': '';
    echo $selected_jabatan;
}
$dept_type = '';
foreach ($depts as $dept) {    
if ($dept_type != $dept['kategori_jabatan']) {
    if ($dept_type != '') {
       echo '<option></option>';
       echo '</optgroup>';
    }
    echo '<optgroup label="'.ucfirst($dept['kategori_jabatan']).'"';
    }
    echo '<option value="'.$dept['jabatan'].'" ' .$selected_jabatan.'>'.htmlspecialchars($dept['jabatan']).'</option>';
    $dept_type = $dept['kategori_jabatan'];
    }
}
if ($dept_type != '') {
echo '</optgroup>';
?>
</select>
```

Viewing dynamic drop down menu was successful, but not the part that it should show my current selected item when I load the page. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do with JavaScript but if you know only PHP, you can do something like this.

1) get value of select from database

```
$value = $row['selectFieldName'];
```

2) than switch this value and when it matches, create select with option selected

```
switch($value):
{
    case 'first':
        here you create select element with option selected that matches   $value;
    break;
}
```

with JavaScript you just output select element value in hidden input and dynamically mark option as selected in case it matches real value.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i think my code is really close to my mission but, it seems like my foreach-loop can't read $selected_jabatan variable from my first while-loop. I've already initiate this variable at the beginning of my code.

Comment: Sorry dude but i can't help you from here, because I need whole code to see where problem is. If you give me github address of your project, maybe I'll be able to find out problem and give you some advice. :)